# مشکل ارور :Page not found (404) در جنگو

Tags: django

I wrote a program in Zang, but whatever I do, it gives this error:

```
404 Using the URLconf defined in storefront.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
admin/
The current path, contact/, did not match any of these.
```

urls.py code:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import save_user

urlpatterns = [
    path('save-user/', save_user, name='save_user'),
]
```

and in project

```
from django.urls import path, include
from playground import views
from django.contrib import admin
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

There is no error during execution, but when I enter the code: `http://localhost:8000/myapp/save-user/` in the browser, it gives an error on that page.

Comment: The urls of your project needs to include the app urls. Something like this:  `path('admin/', admin.site.urls), path('', include('myapp.urls')),`  To be more specific I'd need to see more of your code.

Comment: Please write your question title in English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you start new app in your Django project you should declare app in your `settings.py` and include the specific urls in your `urls.py`.

> settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'my_new_app',
]
```

> urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('route_to_app/', include('my_new_app.urls')),
]
```